# Sitecore 6 WFFM: How to hide fields?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

In Web Forms for Marketers, I have a few fields that I am using to pass values to the pipeline processors and to append CSS code to the form.

I don't want these fields to appear on the form. How can I mark a field to be invisible? Right now I am doing this via CSS, but I am quite sure there must be a better way to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Single Line Text field class and change the container CSS class to your own CSS class that hides the field and label.  You can also add value to that field when the form is loaded through the querystring.

Comment: An example would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a Hidden Field type in WFFM.  Could you use that?

Comment: I also thought I saw a Hidden Field type once, but on this version (2.3) these are the only field types I see out of the box: Single-Line Text, Multiple Line-Text, Password, Email, Telephone, SMS-MMS Telephone, Number, Date, Date Picker, Checkbox, File Upload, Drop List, List Box, Radio List, Checkbox List, Captcha, Password confirmation, Credit Card.

Comment: You are right Francesco, I even don't find any hidden field. I download all the WFFM version and check the dlls, but "Hidden Field" class is never defined by SiteCore (May need confirmation from SiteCore). Did you find any solution?